# Convert nvarchar date (DD/MM/YYYY) to Date Period (YYYY_MM)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert this into a period format, so e.g. 2018_05 (YYYY_MM). currently the data is in DD/MM/YYYY format.

I tried a cast code but it returns me YYYY_DD.

```
SELECT   
CASE WHEN RESERVED_FIELD_4 IS NULL THEN NULL
     ELSE cast(year(RESERVED_FIELD_4) as Nvarchar (4)) 
     +'_'+right('00'+cast(month(RESERVED_FIELD_4)   as Nvarchar (2)),2)
END AS [DATAFEED_PERIOD]
```

I expect/want to see YYYY_MM.

Comment: Code seems OK, can you share an example? The problem might be RESERVED_FIELD_4 data type.

Comment: String/date functions are highly vendor-specific. It's going to be very hard to answer this question without knowing what rdbms you are working with.

Comment: The result at the moment is that oneDATAFEED_PERIOD
2017_01
RESERVED_FIELD_4
01/02/2017                         But it should return 2017_02 in datafeedperiod, as February is the correct month.

Comment: Also, what's the data type of `RESERVED_FIELD_4`?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: Reserved Field 4 is the date i want to be converted into YYYY_MM. I renamed it in the new col in Datafeed as this describes it clearer what it is.

Comment: Sorry what is a dbms? I am quite basic SQL user.

Comment: [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `RESERVED_FIELD_4` is a string type (`char`/`nchar`/`varchar`/`nvarchar`) the simplest solution would be to use `substring`:

```
CASE
WHEN RESERVED_FIELD_4 IS NULL THEN NULL
ELSE SUBSTRING(RESERVED_FIELD_4, 7, 4) + '_'+ SUBSTRING(RESERVED_FIELD_4, 4, 2)
END AS [DATAFEED_PERIOD]
```

If it's a `date`/`datetime`/`datetime2` data type, the simplest solution would be to use `format`:

```
FORMAT(RESERVED_FIELD_4, 'yyyy_MM')
```

But for better performance you can use `convert` and `stuff`:

```
SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(char(6), RESERVED_FIELD_4, 112), 5, 0, '_')
```

In case your format is actually `d/m/y` the simplest option is to convert to date and than back to string:

```
SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(char(6), CONVERT(Date, RESERVED_FIELD_4, 103), 112), 5, 0, '_')
```

Comment: THIS one solved it, thanks you so much ! CASE
WHEN RESERVED_FIELD_4 IS NULL THEN NULL
ELSE SUBSTRING(RESERVED_FIELD_4, 7, 4) + '_'+ SUBSTRING(RESERVED_FIELD_4, 4, 2)
END AS [DATAFEED_PERIOD]

Comment: only problem with this code is that if the reserved field 4 does not have 00 (2) digits format, then it doesnt work correctly. how can i modify that in case it is 7/2/2018 that it is still converted to 2018_02?

Answer (score 1):

This is the common problem of storing a date with a `VARCHAR` column. You are guessing that the stored pattern is `DD/MM/YYYY` but the SQL engine doesn't know that and is currently assuming the `MM/DD/YYYY` pattern.

Please check these results:

```
-- MM/DD/YYYY
SELECT
    DAY  ('05/01/2019'),        -- 1
    MONTH('05/01/2019')         -- 5

-- DD/MM/YYYY
SELECT
    DAY  ('25/05/2019'),        -- Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string
    MONTH('25/05/2019')         -- Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

To display what you want correctly use string functions:

```
SELECT
    RIGHT(RESERVED_FIELD_4, 4) + '_' + SUBSTRING(RESERVED_FIELD_4, 4, 2)
```

But you should actually fix the values on your `VARCHAR` column, cast them to `DATE` and store the values as `DATE`.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD ReservedField4Date DATE

UPDATE YourTable SET 
    ReservedField4Date = CONVERT(DATE, 
        RIGHT(RESERVED_FIELD_4, 4)                      -- Year
        + '-' + SUBSTRING(RESERVED_FIELD_4, 4, 2)       -- Month
        + '-' + LEFT(RESERVED_FIELD_4, 2))              -- Day

ALTER TABLE YourTable DROP COLUMN RESERVED_FIELD_4

EXEC sp_rename 'SchemaName.YourTable.ReservedField4Date', 'RESERVED_FIELD_4', 'COLUMN'
```

Beware that changing the column type might affect other queries that assume this is a `VARCHAR` column.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do conversations ? :

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), CONVERT(date, RESERVED_FIELD_4, 101), 102), '.', '_')
```

This assumes `RESERVED_FIELD_4` is `date` type.

Comment: reserved field 4 is nvarchar, so that one doesnt work

Comment: @Robert. . . then convert it to `date` first.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL-SERVER you can use 'format'

```
format(dy,@your_date) as day_of_year

month(@your_date) as month
```

Try this:

```
Select concat(month(@your_date),'_'year(@your_date)) as your_period
```

[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is a reference

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in DD/MM/YYYY format, then it is being stored as a string.  Hence, string functions come to mind:

```
select right(RESERVED_FIELD_4) + '_' + substrint(RESERVED_FIELD_4, 4, 2)
```

Comment: CASE
  WHEN RESERVED_FIELD_4 IS NULL THEN NULL
  ELSE SUBSTRING(RESERVED_FIELD_4, 7, 4) + '_'+ SUBSTRING(RESERVED_FIELD_4, 4, 2)
  END AS [DATAFEED_PERIOD] this code is working fine now, but not if the string is d/m/yyyy, how can i change it so it adds a leading zero in case it is not in dd/mm/yyyy format?